# Cardboard android inputs we can get

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

Hi everyone I want to know what kind of inputs we can have/use in Android cardboard I know there is the Magnet on the cardboard but is there something else ?

Answer (score 1):

For allowing the user to interact with user interfaces, like in game menus, HUD elements etc, you can put a small dot on the center of the screen and make it child to the cameras so that it does not move when you turn your head.

You can imitate simple mouse functionality by this. Whenever the dot overlaps a UI-Element or object , you start a timer and put some animation. If the dot keeps overlapping for 2-4 sec, you register a click on that location.

This will help you understand what i'm saying : 
www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSUjjCS6UPc

Other than this, the best way to interact with VR content is using a game controller.